# Raspberry pi pico communication Permission Error

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I try to send a Serial from PC:

```
import serial
import time

port = "COM9"
baud_rate = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud_rate)

data = "test\n"
ser.write(data.encode())

ser.close
```

to the Raspberry pi pico:

```
import time
from machine import Pin
import sys

while True:
    v = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    print(v.lower)
```

But I just got the error COM9 Access Denied(COM9 is where my PICO port)

#I'm new to raspberry pi pico

I try to find solution but i still don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

A permission denied error is most likely due to your port being currently unavailable. This means that the device *is* connected, but a different program is accessing it. As it works in Windows (and perhaps also other OSes) only one program can access a Serial port. Assuming that you are not intending to access the port with multiple programs than this is how you could resolve your issue:

- **Check if the port device is connected and the COM port available**. In Windows, open the device manager (`WIN` + `X` + `M`) and look under `Ports`. If there is no entry for Ports then your device is most likely not connected or unreachable.
- **Close any programs that might be accessing the port**. Many IDEs or plugins that support microcontroller development have some sort of serial monitor built in. This could be for instance the Arduino IDE, Thonny or a VSCode plugin like MicroPico. You'll find that the REPL for instance uses the Serial port under the hood. These programs often connect automatically to the COM port if it is available. Closing these programs, closing the connection manually or editing the setting to not connect by default, will most likely solve your issue.

Good luck, I hope this helps